# Run a script after lid is opened

Tags: ubuntu, suspend

I would like to run a script after my laptop lid is opened. is there anything like `rc.local` that is run after the laptop wakes up after suspending?

I use Ubuntu 12

(I need it because some of the systems settings are reset after the lid is closed)

Comment: See this (possible duplicate) at `superuser.com`: ["*Is there a way to call a script when Ubuntu wakes up from suspend/hibernate?*"](http://superuser.com/q/60473/102592)

Comment: What I didn't stress before: the answer to the linked question is valuable since it points out that *this is probably a bug, you shouldn't have to work around this*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the [pm-utils](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pm-utils) package.
I don't know if this is installed by default on Ubuntu.
You can then write a [hook script](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pm-utils#Creating_your_own_hooks) (at e.g. `/etc/pm/sleep.d/00_my_resume_hook`) such as

```
#!/bin/sh
case "${1}" in
    hibernate)
        # nothing
    ;;
    resume|thaw)
        #your script here
    ;;
esac
```

I may have glossed over some essential details here.

Comment: I'd recommend using the `/etc/acpi/handler.sh` script.

Comment: So I have `/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh`, but not `/etc/acpi/handler.sh`. Is this just something I fill out? Any more information regarding this?